# Advanced custom field individual value for individual post in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to show a premium tag beside post that have a 'yes' value selected in an advanced custom field named 'ispremium'. Basically there are two values in ispremium radiobutton field as 'yes' and 'no' I want when 'yes' value is selected for a post then it will show a premium tag beside post title.

I am trying this with following code but problem is that when one post is selected as 'yes' it is showing premium tag for all posts.

```
 <?php
        $posts = get_posts(array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'meta_key' => 'ispremium',
        'meta_value' => 'yes'
        ));

          if($posts)
             {echo '<span class="scriptolution-express"> Premium </span>';}
 ?>
```

Comment: Are you trying to get all posts that have `isPremium=yes` OR get ALL posts and show `Premium` posts only if they `isPremium=yes` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want list of premiun posts:

```
$posts = get_posts(
        array(
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'meta_query' => array
            (
                array
                (
                    'key' => 'ispremium',
                    'value' => 'yes',
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

However if you want to list ALL the posts and show `Premium` text for only premium posts then do this:

```
    $posts = get_posts(
        array(
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_type' => 'post', 
        )
    );
    if($posts)
    {
        ...
        ...
        if(get_field('isPremium') == 'yes')
            echo '<span class="scriptolution-express"> Premium </span>';
        ...
        ...
    }
```

Comment: hi thanks for your reply. i want to list ALL the posts and show Premium text for only premium posts but with this code premium tag is not showing

Comment: is the followig code inside the posts loop? and have to set up curent post?. if not, changing the if condition to this might fix the issue: `if(get_field('isPremium', $post->ID) == 'yes')`